# Error when adding jpa repositories to spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to use spring repositories in my project but when i try to configure like this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring
 i got error

```
Error occured processing XML 'org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ Environment;'. See Error Log for more details
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>PiManager</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd ">
<context:component-scan base-package="org.inz.controller" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.inz.repositories"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PiManagerPersistance" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.inz.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER"/>
            <!--<property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL"/>-->
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=PiManager"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

And tomcat output:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454) ~[spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
lis 28, 2015 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 22 more    

lis 28, 2015 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
lis 28, 2015 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/PiManager] startup failed due to previous errors
lis 28, 2015 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
16:30:12.262 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Nov 28 16:30:11 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
16:30:12.264 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Nov 28 16:30:11 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4785) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5404) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
16:30:12.265 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Nov 28 16:30:11 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4785) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5404) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
lis 28, 2015 4:30:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5404)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Edit:

My pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.inz</groupId>
<artifactId>PiManager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.28</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
        Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
        this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
        spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
        Container and is generally always defined -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
        Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
        DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
        spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
        and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
        JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
        Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
        Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
        Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
        TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
        the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you post the part of your pom file where you are listing your spring dependencies?

Comment: This is a Spring dependency clash issue, but I can't spot the exact place. First I would upgrade to a more recent version of spring (like 4.1.6.RELEASE), then - if the problem persists - check all the spring libraries on the classpath. Not only the entries from the pom, but the transitive dependencies included. Likely one of the spring dependency will be still 3.something. That needs to be explicitly included (with version 4) to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some libary version incompatiblity between Spring-Data-JPA 1.9.1 and Spring 4.0.1. So update your Spring Dependencies at least to Spring 4.1.8

See [Spring Data JPA Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) Doc, [Chapter 2.2 Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework)

> The current version of Spring Data modules require Spring Framework in
>   version 4.1.8.RELEASE or better. The modules might also work with an
>   older bugfix version of that minor version. However, using the most
>   recent version within that generation is highly recommended.

*And also have a look at the section above [2.1. Dependency management with Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-boot)*

So take your pom and replace `4.0.1.RELEASE` with `4.1.8.RELEASE`:

```
<org.springframework.version>4.1.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

Comment: Ok that's help, tomcat don't show error but in my xml file i still see "Error occured processing XML 'org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/"

Comment: I think that incompatiblity is the cause, because of this two lines from the stacktrace:  `at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:64)`  and `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;`

Comment: Still dont know how to fix this. I'm fresh in java

Comment: @Lukaszaq: take your pom and replace 4.0.1.RELEASE with 4.1.8.RELEASE:

Comment: @RaIph:  I alredy do that but. App works but intelisense still shown me an error.

Comment: Eclipse, Error occured processing XML 'org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ Environment;'.

Comment: This is an error within exclipe, that is shown in the ERROR-view?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, and as stated earlier it was to do with latest version of spring-data-jpa version being incompatible with older version of spring.
I did use older version of spring-data-jpa to resolve this issue